# CBCentralManager disconnects from peripheral whenever I try to write data to device?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral, cbcentralmanager

I have a device which I connect to using BLE. I start by checking if BLE is powered on, if so, I start scanning. Then after the device is discovered, I store the peripheral in a variable, then I try to connect to it. The connection succeeds. After that, I starting discovering the services and characteristics, and I manage to read them successfully. The problem is whenever I try to write data to the device I always get this error.

```
Domain=CBErrorDomain Code=7 "The specified device has disconnected from us." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The specified device has disconnected from us.
```

Here is my code:

```
public func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager)
{
    switch central.state {
    case .unauthorized:
        print("App does not support BLE")

    case .poweredOff:
        print("Bluetooth is turned off")

    case .poweredOn:
        print("Bluetooth is turned on")
        print("Start scanning peripherals...")
        central.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)

    default:
        break
    }

}

// To receive cell broadcast data
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {

    let device = Device();

    if(device.fromScanData(peripheral: peripheral, name: peripheral.name, rssi: RSSI.intValue, advertisementData: advertisementData))
    {

        if(device.Name.isEmpty || device.Name.count == 0){
            return;
        }

        if(device.SN.isEmpty || device.SN.count != 8){
            return;
        }

        if self.device.SN == device.SN
        {
            if !isDeviceConnected
            {
                print("Stop scanning")
                print("Connecting...")

                self.peripheral = peripheral
                self.peripheral?.delegate = self
                bluetoothManager.stopScan()
                bluetoothManager.connect(self.peripheral!, options: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {

    print("Connected successfully");
    print("Trying to get equipment services and features...");

    device.Peripheral = peripheral
    self.peripheral?.discoverServices(nil)
}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didFailToConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {

    print("Failed to connect");
}


func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {

    print("Connection has been disconnected");
    isDeviceConnected = false;

}

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?){

    guard let services = peripheral.services else {
        if error != nil
        {
            print("Did Discover Services Error:\(String(describing: error!))")
        }
        else
        {
            print("Empty services")
        }
        return
    }


    print("Device Services......");
    print("-------------- （"+peripheral.identifier.uuidString+"）Service Services information： --------------------");

    print("Number of services：\(services.count)")

    for service in services
    {
        print("---- Service UUID：\(service.uuid) -----");
        self.peripheral?.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service);
    }

}

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?){

    guard let characteristics = service.characteristics else {

        if error != nil
        {
            print("Did Discover Characteristics Error：\(String(describing: error!))")
        }
        else
        {
            print("Empty Characteristics")
        }

        return
    }

    print("Feature Characteristic UUID List：");

    for characteristic in characteristics
    {
        print("UUID: \(characteristic.uuid)");

        self.peripheral?.readValue(for: characteristic);

    }
}


func checkToken() {

    print("Start Writing")

    device.IsSaveOverwrite = true
    let characteristic = characteristicList[characteristicHandle.GetCharacteristicUUID(type: .IsSaveOverwrite)]

    let data = characteristicHandle.GetValue(device: device, type: .IsSaveOverwrite)

    peripheral?.writeValue(data, for: characteristic!, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse);
}

//Read the property successfully callback
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {

    if(error != nil)
    {
        print("Did Update Characteristic with UUID \(characteristic.uuid) Error：\(String(describing: error!))")
        return;
    }

    readConfigs.ConfigRespond(uuid: characteristic.uuid.uuidString);
    device = characteristicHandle.SetDevice(device: device, type: characteristicHandle.GetCharacteristicType(uuid: characteristic.uuid), bytes: characteristic.value!);

    // Check if all characteristics have been read, if so, start writing
    if readConfigs.IsComplete() && readConfiguration == false
    {
        readConfiguration = true
        hideActivityIndicator()
        print("Read all characeteristics")

        checkToken()
    }
}

// Never gets called
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didWriteValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {

    print("Write Config")

}
```

Could someone please point out what am missing?

Comment: It is possibly an issue with your peripheral.  Also, how much data are you trying to write? A good start is to get the light blue app from the App Store and try and use it to write data to your peripheral. If it also disconnects then you know the problem isn't your code.

Comment: You should also check for an error in `didWriteValueFor`